# Динамическое добавление компонента Angular 7

Tags: angular2, angular7

Вопрос к знатокам:

Есть у меня HTML, который с БД прилетает. После встраивания оного в страницу, я выхватываю из него div по id. Делаю из него ElementRef. До этого момента всё хорошо. Проблема в том, что я не могу в него положить компонент, который я создал динамически ч-з componentFactoryResolver. Я понимаю, что в данном виде это невозможно.

И вот вопрос:

Возможно ли получить ViewContainerRef из ElementRef?

Comment: твой вопрос непонятен, если честно :) создай пример на stackblitz или codesandbox

Comment: Нашёл ответ на свой вопрос в иностранных интернетах.
Статья [тут](https://hackernoon.com/angular-pro-tip-how-to-dynamically-create-components-in-body-ba200cc289e6)